# Jmeter giving problems with xpath

Tags: html, xpath, jmeter

I have been attempting to use JMeter's XPath extractor for a while now, and have been unable extract anything at all.

I have been using `Firebug` to give me the XPath of a link by right-clicking on `a->Copy XPath` which gives me the following 
`/html/body/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a`.

I have been testing this (`/html/body/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a/@href`) in Firefox's `XPath Checker` which successfully returns all the links on the page.

I am fairly certain that my problem is with JMeter, and not my XPath syntax etc.
Has anyone else had similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** **First of all:** since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

**2.** XPath query like your above (`/html/body/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a/@href`) looks not very accurate. Suppose you can try to use something like the following:

```
//a[@id="..."][@name="..."][text()="..."]/@href
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ensured that the **Use Tidy (tolerant parser))** option was checked so thanks for that tip. The XPath query was one which firebug gave me directly from the source page, so it should be fine... however i will try `//a/@href` to see if i can get any results.

Comment: I think you are right about the XPath query... i tried something a little more general `//a/@href` and got something back so thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alies Belik I have issue about the xpath, please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039199/how-to-test-cas-with-jmeter