# How to test CAS with jmeter?

Tags: xpath, single-sign-on, jmeter, cas

- request:

  I send a "get" http request, has no parameters;
   
  path: `http://192.168.22.139:8080/KSP`
- response:

  ```
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required/>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required/>
  <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-697-vbNmm6NKOZ0cd7Wg1ywzbMKLa0DnOc" />
  <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e1s1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
  ```

And I add two XPath Extractor to get `lt` and `execution`:

- reference name: `lt`;
   
  xPath query: `//*[@id="login"]/input[3]`
- reference name: `execution`;
  xPath query: `//*[@id="login"]/input[4]`

[image]

Then I send another request with `username/password/service/It/execution/_eventId`:

[image]

**Error**: ticket and execution I get is empty, I get the xpath by chrome, so what is the problem?

Comment: The "CSS/JQuery Extractor" also can get the "lt". "input[name=lt]"

Comment: The "CSS/JQuery Extractor" also can get the "lt". "input[name=lt]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the first response, can use **Regular Expression Extractor** to extract ticke and lt.
[image: extract ticket]

Then send the second request with parameter:

> `username/password/It/execution/_eventId/_eventId`
>   [image]

By the way, you should add **HTTP Cookie Manager**,
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I didnot see parameters of your **first** request. At least I didnot see the **lt**.

The second request should be a GET request, and the parameters are: **service** and **ticket**(This is not jsessionid, the value is generated by CAS, and it is the same with the parameter **lt** in the first request to the CAS login ).

Comment: I have re-edit my question; In my first request, how can I get the "It"? From the response 1, I get the ticket. In first request, what parameter do I need send and what about second request?

Comment: @OliviaWang ,when you open the CAS login page, there should be a hidden input with name "lt", which you can get with **Regular Expression Extractor**.

Comment: Your suggestion is right, I have re-edit my question. The problem now is I cannot get "lt" and "execution", please help me.

Comment: Maybe youcan try **Regular Expression Extractor** with Regular Expression: `lt=(.+)`

Comment: I have vote up your answer, but the question still have issue about "XPath Extractor", so I am sorry...

Comment: can you log in with JMeter now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41497/discussion-between-bugdaily-and-olivia-wang)

Answer (score 3):

There is a few things you need to change in the second request:

- add `execution` parameter (extract it from the first request, eg. with [`XPath Extractor`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [`Regular Expression Extractor`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)),

  - the XPath expression would be something like `.//*[@id='fm1']//*[@name='execution']/@value`
- add `_eventId=submit` parameter,
- the `lt` parameter (the login ticket) should be extracted from the login form, too - it changes each time; see `XPath Extractor` or `Regular Expression Extractor`,

  - XPath expression: `.//*[@id='fm1']//*[@name='lt']/@value`,
- not required, but will look nicer - change GET to POST.

Comment: Your suggestion is right, I have re-edit my question. The problem now is I cannot get "lt" and "execution", please help me.

Comment: Still cannot get "lt" and "execution", I use "Regular Expression Extractor" instead and it works well. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing CAS login itself I can suggest using [JMeter HTTP Proxy server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) to record login process, catch all values which are being passed, detect those, which are dynamic and deal with them via Regular Expression Extractor, XPath, Beanshell, etc. Post Processors - what you're most comfortable with.

In case if your application is behind CAS I guess that CAS login simply adds a cookie and your application considers user authenticated basing on it. In this case you can simply store cookies somewhere in CSV file and use them via [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to simulate authenticated users.